# Is differentiability a necessary or sufficient condition for a critical point $c$ of a function $f$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I do understand that the gradient of $f$ should be zero. This is for the purpose of classifying local extrema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neither necessary nor sufficient. By definition a critical point of $f$ is point $x$ where either $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ does not exist. So differentiability is not necessary. If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x)\neq 0$ then $x$ is not a critical point, so differentiability is not sufficient.